# PHP json_decode not working as expected if there is \x14

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wanted to `json_decode` the variable `$string`, but it didn't return anything, here is the code:

```
$string = '[{"name":"hello", "weird":"\x14"}]'; // this is not working - \x14 causing the problem
$json= json_decode($string, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
```

but

```
$string = '[{"name":"hello", "weird":"something normal"}]'; // this is working
```

So i have tried to echo `\x14` in online playground for PHP and it turned out to be a square box :

```
<?php
$ReceivedData = "\x14";
echo $ReceivedData; // returns =>
```

How can I json_decode this string?

Comment: what is the actual string you're passing? and why you're decoding a string? it should be JSON which has to be decoded and converted back to array

Comment: It's not a valide json. You can check there : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. You have to escape \ => "\\x14" and not "\x14"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @svgta says, the format isn't correct. In JSON, it would normally be `"\u0014"`, for Unicode and correct UTF-8 support. This can effectively be validated by calling PHP's `json_encode()` function:

The test case in PHP:

```php
<?php

$var = [
    (object)[
        'name' => 'hello',
        'weird' => "\x14", // PHP syntax https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#:~:text=g.%20%22%5C400%22%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22%5C000%22)-,%5Cx,-%5B0%2D9A%2DFa
    ]
];

print '$var = ' . var_export($var, true) . "\n";

$json = json_encode($var);

print '$json = ' . $json . "\n";

$decoded_json = json_decode($json);

print '$decoded_json = ' . var_export($decoded_json, true) . "\n";
```

Output (the squares don't seem to display here but they do in the console):

```
$var = [
  0 => (object)[
     'name' => 'hello',
     'weird' => '',
  ],
]
$json = [{"name":"hello","weird":"\u0014"}]
$decoded_json = [
  0 => (object)[
     'name' => 'hello',
     'weird' => '',
  ],
]
```

You can run it online here to see by yourself: https://onlinephp.io/c/e2f69

### Solving your problem

You'll probably have to convert your `\x14` to `\u0014` before calling `json_decode()`. This could be done with a regular expression `\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})`: https://regex101.com/r/4Rxh4u/1

In PHP code:

```php
<?php

// The invalid JSON.
$json = '[{"name":"hello", "weird":"\\x14", "other_weird":"\\xab"}]';

// The regular expression to find all \x## values: \\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})
// I did not handle \x# with only one hexa value but this could be improved.
$regexp = '/\\\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/';

// The replacement is \u#### (4 hexa values).
$subst = '\\\\u00$1';

$corrected_json = preg_replace($regexp, $subst, $json);

print "\$json = $json\n";
print "\$corrected_json = $corrected_json\n";

$var = json_decode($corrected_json);

print '$var = ' . var_export($var, true) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
$json = [{"name":"hello", "weird":"\x14", "other_weird":"\xab"}]
$corrected_json = [{"name":"hello", "weird":"\u0014", "other_weird":"\u00ab"}]
$var = [
  0 => (object)[
     'name' => 'hello',
     'weird' => '',
     'other_weird' => '«',
  ],
]
```

Run it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/35b8a